# UK Kids Series 90's/early 2000's Identification

Tags: story-identification, tv

So I remember watching a TV show as a kid in the 90s were a group of kids find themselves trapped somewhere else, where:

- medieval level technology, possibly saxon/viking/celtic theme
- There's a scene with a king/queen or lord/lady where they try to explain or are captured
- everybody there has green blood and they're surprised when the kids have red blood
- the kids try to prove were they came from by showing them a camcorder with a display and play back footage from a car journey, which does not go down well
- there's some sort of thing related to electricity going on with this world being parallel to our own, with some people wielding is as orange lightning with what look like dark tops with tubes or something, there's an actress with long ginger hair wearing one but the memory's hazy
- the final scene when they're back in their own world has a cash machine, but instead of dispensing cash there's spears and arrow heads thrust through the opening
- It was not animated, or a cartoon, real actors

Any help identifying?

Comment: Of note, the electricity related thing also had locations that had importance, I'm not sure how. It's also definately not spellbinder, though that does bare some similarities ( and a great deal more australians )

Answer (score 3):

Could it be the Australien series "Spellbinder" from 1995 - three seasons?

In the first season, a brother and sister (I think, it's a long time since I saw it) stumble into a different world while on a family-trip.  Second season is about a girl (same as in first?) ending up there.

(Edit: Oops! - looking at the trailers I seem to have mixed somethings together... no matter.)

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112174/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2

Don't know about green blood, but they use suites that shoots lightning-bolts and there is a ginger-haired woman.

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112174/mediaviewer/rm3899398912

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112174/mediaviewer/rm3949730560

Trailers:

Comment: I found this in my searches, and believe me the ginger haired woman made me think I'd found it, but alas no. The footage style is different, and the entire things on youtube, so I went through it and couldn't find any of the scenes I remembered

Comment: I think there were only two seasons, not three.  Also, OP, the ginger-haired villain tries out a newer, more high-tech-looking power suit in episodes 23 onwards of Series 1 - maybe that might ring a bell?